# Create multiple columns within groupby for calculation?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
SKU,Date,Inventory,Sales,Incoming
2010,2017-01-01 0:00:00,85,126,252
2010,2017-02-01 0:00:00,382,143,252
2010,2017-03-01 0:00:00,414,139,216
2010,2017-04-01 0:00:00,468,120,216
7770,2017-01-01 0:00:00,7,45,108
7770,2017-02-01 0:00:00,234,64,216
7770,2017-03-01 0:00:00,160,69,36
7770,2017-04-01 0:00:00,150,50,72
7870,2017-01-01 0:00:00,41,29,36
7870,2017-02-01 0:00:00,95,18,36
7870,2017-03-01 0:00:00,112,16,36
7870,2017-04-01 0:00:00,88,19,0
```

Inventory Quantity is the "actual" recorded quantity, which may differ from the hypothetical remaining quantity, which is what I am trying to calculate.

Sales Quantity actually extends much longer into the future. In those rows, the other two columns will have NA.

I want to create the following:

1. Take only the first `Inventory` value of each SKU
2. Use the first value to calculate the hypothetical remaining quantity by using a recursive formula `[Earliest inventory] - [Sales for that month] - [Incoming qty for that month]` (Note: `Earliest inventory` is a fixed quantity for each SKU). Store the output in a column called "End of Month Part 1".
3. Create another column called "Buy Quantity" with the following criteria: If remaining quantity is less than 50, then create a new column that indicates the buy amount (let's say it's 30 for all 3 SKUs) (i.e. increase the quantity by 30). If the remaining quantity is more than 50, then the buy amount is zero.
4. Create another column called "End of Month Part 2" that adds "End of Month Part 1" with "Buy Quantity"

I am able to obtain the first quantity of each SKU using the following code, and merge it into a column called `first_qty` into the dataset

```
first_qty_series = dataset.groupby(by=['SKU']).nth(0)['Inventory']
first_qty_series = pd.DataFrame(dataset).reset_index().rename(columns={'Inventory': 'Earliest inventory'})
dataset = pd.merge(dataset, pd.DataFrame(first_qty_series), on='SKU' )
```

As for the remainder quantity, I thought of using cumsum() on the two columns `dataset['Sales']` and `dataset['Incoming']` but I think it won't work because the cumsum() will sum across ALL SKUs.

That's why I think I need to perform the calculation in groupby. But I don't know what else to do.

(Edit:) Expected output is:
[image]

Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you show a simple example for the output that you are expecting?

Comment: could you replace the data you posted with `print(df.to_dict())` it can be used by others to see your question? It'll be easier to reproduce your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @nahusznaj, what do you mean? I thought the data is reproducible by copying the rows and saving it as csv.

Comment: @min2bro I have updated already

Comment: I meant to say that if you put this instead of the table it would be easier: `dictionary = {'SKU': {0: '2010', 1: '2010'}, 'Date': {0: '2017-01-01 0:00:00', 1: '2017-02-01 0:00:00'}, 'Inventory': {0: '85', 1: '382'}, 'Sales': {0: '126', 1: '143'}, 'Incoming': {0: '252', 1: '252'}}` and then one can just copy paste that dictionary and run `df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)`. I meant that this would be easier to copy and reproduce. It's a small detail I guess

Comment: oh I see. Sorry about that.

Comment: check this: df['End of Month Part 1']=  df.groupby(by=['SKU']).filter(lambda x: (x['SKU'] == x['SKU']).any()).iloc[0]['Inventory']- df['Sales'] - df['Incoming'], I have done one column..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do the 4 columns you want.

1 - Another method, using `loc` and `drop_duplicates` to fill the first row for each 'SKU' with the value from 'Inventory', and then use `ffill` to fill the following rows, but your method is good.

```
dataset.loc[dataset.drop_duplicates(['SKU']).index,'Earliest inventory'] = dataset['Inventory']
dataset['Earliest inventory'] = dataset['Earliest inventory'].ffill().astype(int)
```

2 - Indeed you need `cumsum` and `groupby` to create the column 'End of Month Part 1', not on the column 'Earliest inventory' as the value is the same on every row for a same 'SKU'. Note: according to your result (and logic), I  change the `-` with `+` before the column 'Incoming', and if I misunderstood the problem, just change the sign.

```
dataset['End of Month Part 1'] = (dataset['Earliest inventory'] 
                                   - dataset.groupby('SKU')['Sales'].cumsum() 
                                    + dataset.groupby('SKU')['Incoming'].cumsum())
```

3 - The column 'Buy Quantity' can be implemented using `loc` again meeting the condition on value less than 50 in column 'End of Month Part 1', then `fillna` with 0

```
dataset.loc[dataset['End of Month Part 1'] <= 50, 'Buy Quantity'] = 30
dataset['Buy Quantity'] = dataset['Buy Quantity'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

4 - Finally the last column is just adding the two lasts created

```
dataset['End of Month Part 2'] = dataset['End of Month Part 1'] + dataset['Buy Quantity']
```

If I understood well the 4 points, you should get the dataset with the new columns